# listview items to a single field in ms access table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to put multiple items from a List view to a single field in MS-Access.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAi3g.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSyJb.png

sorry for the trouble. I can't post pictures yet..

```
conn.Open()
cmd.Commandtext = "INSERT INTO tblPRDraft VALUES(...'",'" & lvItems.FocusedItem.Text & "')"

cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

It only saves the first item.

Comment: I'm not sure is that possible... You can store as single record delimited with some char. For example : `item1+","+item2+","+item3+","+...` and so on. In this example, delimiter is `,`.

Comment: It would be better if you just use _Reference Tables_.